# Is this service considered "an API"? Could it benefit from being Restful?

Tags: rest, api, web-applications, web-services, web-api

I'm confused about the meaning of API, specially in the context of REST. I'm thinking of one example.

My company creates an application that runs on a server (the "backend"). (JavaScript in Node.js)

To use it, my company also creates a user interface that runs on the browser of the client's computer (the "frontend").(React.js).

When the user enters [www.my-company.com](http://www.my-company.com), they are provided with our frontend. They click around it which sends specific requests that access specific methods "exposed" in our backend. It responds with mostly JSONs with data.

**The backend is made to be accessed only by our frontend. We don't want anything else making requests to it.**

Question 1: Is the service that I just described "an API"? A lot of people talk about "developing APIs" and I want to know if that's what *we* are doing.

Question 2: Is our service benefited by making it REST? After reading about it I think it only benefits services that can be accessed "by anyone's app", instead of "just by our website".

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76356691/is-this-service-considered-an-api-could-it-benefit-from-being-restful "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat i was told there to post here... and here im being told to post there?

Comment: @JuanPerez - it's just that the exact same question shouldn't be posted on more than one site at the same time, because this is a Q&A site, and those looking for a potential solution might stumble upon one, but not the other, etc. (Decide where you want to post, then delete the other). Regarding your question - it's a bit of a terminology mixup that's proliferated in recent past. When people say they are developing "an API" 1/2...

Comment: ...what they mean and what they *should* be saying is that they are developing a web service, which includes defining the endpoints, request and response bodies, etc. - this set of endpoints and data structures, along with what they are for, what they do from the consumer perspective, is the interface to the service - a.k.a. its Application Programming Interface (API). The API as a concept is not specific to web services, and does not have to be realized through web requests - e.g. any component, library or framework has an API, a database has an API, etc. 2/2

Comment: FYI: `The backend is made to be accessed only by our frontend. We don't want anything else making requests to it.` this is not possible once your web app is published (no matter if it's server-side rendering or SPA-API). The app is visible to everyone, endpoints are visible to everyone, and sites are accessible by all sorts of bots and scrappers, you can't prevent this from happing unless you add a security component in front. Don't conflate accessibility with authorization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, what you describe is an API. Any software interface which is designed to be called by software clients is an API. Your architecture sound like RPC (remote procedure calls) over HTTP, which is a common form of API.
2. Probably not. REST is not designed for API's. REST is an architectural style optimized for large-scale distributed hypermedia. It is not designed for API's like yours, where a single frontend communicate with a single backend.

Answer (score 3):

I don't disagree with JacquesB's answer per se but the answer kind of depends on what you mean by RESTful.  If you mean using HTTP verbs correctly and structuring your API around the concept of resources, then I would say definitely yes, it can be helpful.  For example, simply using GET for retrievals and following the requirements that it be '[safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Safe/HTTP)', you can get client-side caching with no additional effort.  It also often leads to easier integration with client-side libraries that expect you to conform to these standards.  As far as we know, you may already be doing this.

But if you are talking about REST [as defined by Fielding](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) such as [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) (worst acronym ever) and other more hifalutin kind of ideas, it's probably overkill.

Comment: HTTP caching is designed for caching web pages and images and such. I don't see how it is useful in the context of an API client? E.g. if you fetch a JSON data object in a javascript client, you just keep the object around as long as you need it. You wouldn't make requests for data you already have and (isn't stale), so request layer caching is not necessary.

Comment: @JacquesB: The argumentation for _any_ client-side cache remains the same regardless of what specific data (or data format) is being cached.

Comment: @JacquesB The argumentation for any **client-side** cache remains the same regardless of what specific data (or data format) is being cached. The argumentations for client-side caches and serverside caches are different, but individually they are consistent for any kind of data that you are working with, regardless of it being JSON data, images, web pages, ...

Comment: @Flater: Yes caching is great, but in a JavaScript client you would just cache data in a variable or whatever. If you don't need to update the data, just don't make a request for it. No need for using the HTTP level caching which is less fine-grained and much more complex to configure.

Comment: @JacquesB: What you're mentioning **is** a form of caching. It is not the only way to cache things. One could also use an existing HTTP caching client pretty much out of the box for the purpose of wrapping it around a REST resource. That is not a must, but it is one way (out of many possible ways) of doing it. I'm not sure why you're arguing for its exclusion as a valid approach.

Comment: @Flater: I'm arguing against client-side HTTP level caching in a JavsScript client because it is next to useless. It can only cache data which is fetched by the client side code, which means the code already have the data! For this reason, client-side frameworks have their own state management libraries.

Comment: @JacquesB: I can make the same argument about browsers being able to store the result they get from a URL and not fetch it a second time. The reason for wanting to cache something is irrespective of the specific data format that is being cached.

Comment: @JacquesB "which means the code already have the data!"  Not necessarily.  Data, especially from APIs can change.  And you do things like put in a [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#if-modified-since) header to only pull data when it is actually changed on the server.  I've never understood why you wouldn't follow HTTP standards when you can.  Did the SOAP-WSDL debacle teach us nothing?

Comment: @JacquesB HTTP level caching is not necessarily happening client-side, but may occur in the intermediaries in the network infrastructure, making responses faster and taking the load off of the server.